# SSAS Opening Balance

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am building a cube in SSAS that uses inventory movement data to show item activity.  A sample of this data can be seen here (hopefully this is readable).

Date = Customer =   Item = Receive Qty   = Ship Qty = Movement

1/1/2000 = Cust123   = Item123 = 100 = 0 =  100

11/5/2011 = Cust123 = Item123 = 10 = 0 = 10

11/6/2011    = Cust123 =    Item123 =   0 =     -5 =    -5

11/7/2011    = Cust123 =    Item123 =   1 =     0 =     1

The goal is to include an opening balance in the cube.  The opening balance for a given date is defined as the sum of all Movement (from the Movement field) for a given customer and item (my fact table contains many different customers and items) for all dates prior to the current date.

So in the sample data, the opening balance for the 11/6/2011 date would be the sum of all Movement (from the Movement field) where the customer and item are a match, and the date is less than 11/6/2011.  Which would go all the way back to 1/1/2000 in my sample data.

Is there a way that MDX could help me accomplish this in my cube?  I am relatively new to SSAS, but I believe there should be a way for me to include some MDX in the Calculations tab correct?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick dirty way would be:

```
sum({null:[Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Lag(1)}, [Measures].[Movement])
```

This assumes a few things:

1. Your `CurrentMember` of the `Date Hierarchy` will be at a day level.
2. Your dataset isn't that big that this sum can be undertaken very quickly.

If you have a much larger dataset and this is slow for you, what you'll want to do is to sum up the previous months (or years, depending on your partition level) first, and then do days of this month on top of it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and dirty solution. Before I test this, my fact table consists of many different customers and items.  Does that need to be taken into account in your MDX solution as well?

Comment: @user1134307 - It will use the current tuple of wherever `Customer` and `Item` are, so this will sum up across whatever `Customer` and `Item` members are at the current location.

Comment: Great, thanks Eric...I'll test this out.  I'm looking at around 700k lines of data in my fact.  Would you call that "big" according to your original post?

Comment: @user1134307 - Not huge, no. If you run into performance issues, we can go start building some more sophisticated logic to get to the answer faster.

Comment: So I'm running into an error Eric.  I have a date dimension, and I've built a Date Hierarchy called Date Hierarchy.  It consists of Date, Year Month, Year Qtr, Year.  I created a Calculation called openbal using your MDX from your solution.  When I drag the new measure into the browswer, it takes some time to calc and then returns #Value! in every row for openbal.  The error says: The level [Date Hierarchy] was not found in the cube when the string [Date].[Date Hierarchy] was parsed.

Comment: Then `[Date].[Date Hierarchy]` isn't the path to that hierarchy. Can you browse that hierarcy? A quick was to see is `select [Date].[Date Hierarchy].DefaultMember on 0 from [cube]`

Comment: Sorry, it should be [Dim Date].[Date Heirarchy].  That way it works.  I think you have given great advice here Eric.  But I think I've discovered that I can't use MDX for this open balance calculation.  Users will ultimatly be interrested in running this cube from Excel, and interested in day-by-day calcs, but more "show me activity for november 2001".  Which means date will not be included in the meansures, but instead user will add a filter for november 2011.  When I remove the date from the browswer and only leave item, the values for openbal disappear.  Thank you again for your help

Comment: I will explore TSQL/SSIS solution to capture openbal prior to cube.  Thanks Eric.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at capturing the running value in the underlying table. It shouldn't be too much to calculate for everything existing, and new data would be a breeze.

You could then use LastNonEmpty measure (in case you have Enterprise edition) and it should be instant-response for any balance anywhere.